# Angular.js: Create 2 html containers using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items, and I'd like to split each half of the items in it's own container.

How can I accomplish this using `ng-repeat`?

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
        <li>Some item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Please provide the codes that you have tried so far and we'll help you from there

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. If you know Angular.js then this info should be enough to understand the question and provide a solution.

Comment: Posting an html div wrapping a list and asking us to write angular controls to repeat it is not **asking for help in fixing any problems** man. In other words, you are just trying to find someone to code angular for you **from scratch**

Comment: It seems @michael-p understood the question better than you

Comment: I definitely understood the question Pier but there was not a single line of angular code in your html and then you state that you haven't tried anything in the comment above. Come on man. Read your question again. You're basically asking for somebody to code it for you. Peace.

Comment: I'm sorry my question bothered you, but as you can see from the answer it was a clear problem with a simple solution.

Comment: I understand Andrew's concern, that in general the OP has to show the code he tried, but there are some times you don't really know in which direction you should go, and here there was one straightforward solution. Pier could have provided a dummy ng-repeat and said that it doesn't work, but I don't think it would have made things better. Anyway, upvoated him because I think the downvote was not deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1 : call slice on the collection***

We can call the `slice` method on the collection :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-init="half = numbers.length / 2">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="number in numbers.slice(0, half)">{{number}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="number in numbers.slice(half)">{{number}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/09y6n6L7/5/)**

---

***Solution 2 : use `limitTo` built-in filter***

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-init="len = numbers.length">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="number in numbers | limitTo: len / 2 + (len % 2)">{{number}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="number in numbers | limitTo: - len / 2">{{number}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fact that we add `len % 2` is for dealing with array oddity.

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/09y6n6L7/4/)**

Comment: Updated the answer so as to show how to deal with array oddity when choosing the `limitTo` solution.